# Factor a polynomial over the reals

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I can't seem to find a function in *Mathematica* that factors a polynomial *over the reals*. Obviously, Factor doesn't work since it works over the integers, over $\mathbb{Z}_p$,  or some algebraic fields extensions of the type $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are algebraic numbers. My question is general, although it arouse from my need to factor over $\mathbb{R}$ the polynomial
$$
f(\lambda) = \lambda^4 + 17\lambda^2+12.
$$
Of course, in this particular case I can find the roots and factor it myself.

Comment: I will be pleased with a numerical solution also.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98098/rewrite-a-real-polynomial-in-real-but-only-linear-and-quadratic-factors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to find the roots, separate into real and complex, further separate the complex ones into conjugate pairs, then reform as a factorization (taking into account the leading coefficient). I'll illustrate with the given example.

```
poly = x^4 + 17 x^2 + 12;
roots = x /. NSolve[poly];
rroots = Select[rts, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]
croots = Complement[roots, rroots];
topquad = Select[croots, Im[#] > 0 &]
mult = Coefficient[poly, x, Exponent[poly, x]]
rfax = x - rroots
cfax = x^2 - 2*x*Re[topquad] + Re[topquad]^2 + Im[topquad]^2

(* Out[54]= {}

Out[56]= {0. + 0.859018 I, 0. + 4.03263 I}

Out[57]= 1

Out[58]= {}

Out[59]= {0.737913 + x^2, 16.2621 + x^2} *)
```

Putting together the result:

```
Apply[Times, Join[{mult}, rfax, cfax]]

(* Out[61]= (0.737913 + x^2) (16.2621 + x^2) *)
```

Comment: After checking for irreducibility (`IrreduciblePolynomialQ[]`) it would be "easier" to use `NumberFieldSignature[]` to get the counts of real roots and complex pairs of roots.

Comment: @EricTowers If working in the setting of approximate numbers and speed is an issue then I would advocate against that unless degree is large enough to make the numerics fail. Even then it is not clear what is the gain to knowing the counts-- one needs actual root values.

Comment: Thank you, this is the nicest numerical solution.Of course it would work also if *Mathematica* can find the complex roots exactly.

Comment: You can replace `NSolve` with `Solve` to get exact roots. To obtain real ones, change the `Select` predicate to `FreeQ[N[#], Complex] &` and similar for separating complex roots with positive vs negative imaginary components.

Answer (score 8):

My knowledge in this area is quite lacking, so there are probably better ways.  The following function will force-factor anything, and will return [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects if necessary.

```
factor[poly_, x_] :=
 Module[{n, nreal},
  n = Exponent[poly, x];
  nreal = CountRoots[poly, x];
  Times @@ Join[
    Table[(x - ToRadicals@Root[poly & /. x -> #, i]), {i, nreal}],
    Table[
     With[{r1 = ToRadicals@Root[poly & /. x -> #, i], 
       r2 = ToRadicals@Root[poly & /. x -> #, i + 1]},
      (x^2 - Expand[(r1 + r2)] x + Expand[r1 r2])
      ],
     {i, nreal + 1, n, 2}
     ]
    ]
  ]
```

This is relying on the ordering used by [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html), described under "Details".  Real roots come first, then complex conjugate pairs.

Example:

```
factor[x^4 + 17 x^2 + 12, x]
(* (17/2 - Sqrt[241]/2 + x^2) (17/2 + Sqrt[241]/2 + x^2) *)
```

Any coefficient in the result will be real, regardless of whether it includes terms that look imaginary in its expression.  Example:

```
factor[x^4 + 1, x]
(* (1 - ((-1)^(1/4) - (-1)^(3/4)) x + x^2) (1 - (-(-1)^(1/4) + (-1)^(3/4)) x + x^2) *)
```

`(-1)^(1/4)` has an imaginary part, but `(-1)^(1/4) + (-1)^(3/4)`, which is the actual coefficient of `x`, doesn't.

Expect not very useful results for cases like this:

```
factor[x^5 + 2 x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, x]
(* (x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 1]) (x^2 +
    Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2] Root[
     1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 3] - 
   x (Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 2] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 3])) (x^2 + 
   Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 4] Root[
     1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 5] - 
   x (Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 4] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + 2 #1^4 + #1^5 &, 5])) *)
```

This is why yarchik's solution is better.

Comment: Thank you, Szabolcs. As expected, for the polynomial $f_1(\lambda) = 180+1027 \lambda ^2+666 \lambda ^4+27 \lambda ^6$ I got bad results :) By the way, your module works for monic polynomials.

Comment: Why not change `Expand` to `ComplexExpand`? Then `factor[x^4 + 1, x]` yields (1 - Sqrt[2] x + x^2) (1 + Sqrt[2] x + x^2)

Answer (score 7):

```
Factor[x^4 + 17 x^2 + 12, Extension -> Sqrt[241]]
(*-(1/4) (-17 + Sqrt[241] - 2 x^2) (17 + Sqrt[241] + 2 x^2)*)
```

The answer to another example can be obtained as follows:

```
f = 180 + 1027 x^2 + 666 x^4 + 27 x^6 
Factor[f, Extension -> { (-293657 + 20 I Sqrt[4568243])^(1/3)}] /. (-293657 + 20 I Sqrt[4568243]) -> a // Simplify
```

Finally a small remark on mathematical side. Sometimes algebraic equations of higher orders (>4) can be solved in radicals. Otherwise solutions for $n=5,6,7$ are known in terms of more general functions, see for instance the wiki article on  the [septic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septic_equation). Very simple solutions are known for trinomial equations $x^n+x-q=0$ in terms of hypergeometric functions ($n\in\mathbb{N}$).  As far as I know, these solutions and more general solutions are not directly implemented in MA. Your two examples are of course solvable because of the substitution $\lambda^2=x$.

Comment: Thank you, but this answers only the particular question. If I have a polynomial of greater degree, this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @Veliko Please, show your polynomial of greater degree then. There is no guarantee i will work in general, but let us try.

Comment: @Veliko What is there are no roots that can be expressed as radicals?  Would you still want it factored in terms of `Root` expressions?

Comment: @yarchik I expect that my polynomials can be expressed as radicals. Otherwise I don't expect a Mathematica solution:) For example, other polynomials are : $f_1(\lambda) = 180 + 1027 \lambda^2 + 666 \lambda^4 + 27 \lambda^6$ and $f_2(\lambda) = 357696+5872364 \lambda ^2+13665873 \lambda ^4+8310318 \lambda ^6+573049 \lambda ^8$.

Comment: @Veliko for your first example see my updated answer.

Comment: @yarchik I don't know if it is from my version of *Mathematica* (7.0) but the addition in your answer doesn't give a real factorization. About the mathematics: I am familiar with Galois theory and my question is tricky. I will, however be pleased with a numerical solution also. In my work it could happen that I need such factorization for bigger odd degrees like 8,10, .. also.

Comment: @Veliko Well, for numerical solutions just use `NSolve`. For the rest, I see what you mean. But are you actually sure it is possible in a *real* form?

Comment: @Veliko If you just need a numerical result, you can use my function as `Chop@N@factor[poly, x]`.  That'll save a bit of time compared to reimplementing the same with `NSolve`.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your efforts. About the real form. Yes, I am sure. A consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra is that every polynomial with real coefficients can be decomposed into irreducible over R polynomials of degree 1 and 2. In other words, the only irreducible polynomials of degree >= 2 are the quadratic polynomials with negative discriminant. Moreover I expect a specific form of these polynomials in my research.